# Which day does "on the day prior to arrival" refer to?

Tags: meaning

Which day does

> by 2pm on the day prior to arrival, which will be DD/MM/YYYY

refer to?

Does it refer to the same day before I arrive at the venue or does it mean the day before the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is beautifully ambiguous, but note the omission of *on*.

If *which* referred to the day of arrival, *on* would normally be included:

> ... by 2pm on the day prior to arrival, which will be on [date].

That is, an arrival happens **on** a particular day; it's not actually a day itself.

Because *on* is omitted in the sentence, the *which* must refer to the day which is mentioned: that's the ***day prior to arrival.***

The date which is shown is the day before arrival.

The sentence would appear to be part of a cancellation or change clause: something like "You must submit any changes by 2pm on the day prior to arrival, which will be [date]." It's entirely reasonable for changes to have to be notified on the day before they actually matter, in order that arrangements can be adjusted. If changes were allowed up to 2pm on the arrival date, there would be very little time to accommodate them.

An improvement would be to make the date explicit and then explain that:

> ...by 2pm on [date], that is, the day prior to arrival.

Comment: Given the frequency of typos in written material, I don't think you can actually conclude anything definite from the OP's sentence.

Comment: An additional ambiguity--is it the day prior to arrival, or before arrival by 2pm on that day.

Answer (score -1):

It means the calendar day (Mon-Tue-Wed-etc.) immediately before the calendar day you will arrive. If you will arrive on the seventh, this means the sixth. If you will arrive on Wednesday, this means Tuesday.